# How to modify the linker configuration file in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker, c-preprocessor, pragma

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION (".myvarloc");
uint8 measurements[30];
```

I have created a array of size 30 in my program.

```
MEMORY
{
        MYMEMORY(rw)   : ORIGIN = 0x00007800,  LENGTH = 5K
}

.myvars (NOLOAD) :
{
  *(. myvarloc)

} > MYMEMORY
```

But how to put the above code in the linker script in my IDE. I am using visual studio C++.

Comment: Do you want measurements to be located at 0x7800?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have to do that exactly.

Comment: Are you aware of the virtual address space that you use? Why do you want to have these data at a virtual address without having it mapped to a specific physical address?

Comment: I want to specify the address in the linker file and later used the same address from the Master (INCA tool )to send and receive value based on the address name.